# gedit text editor - mac os x

Tags: macos, connection, gedit

Does anybody know if you can setup remote connections in gedit(on mac os x snow leopard), so I don't have to keep ftp'ing up seperately.

I know it can be done on Ubuntu but can't figure out how to do it on a mac, if even possible.

Answer (score 0):

An application independent solution for this would be [sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS) on OSX through [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). sshfs is also available for Linux.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I shall look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This sshfs with a GUI is also available via MacPorts.

There is also a possibility of automatic upload after each file save in Transmit and in Cyberduck (FTP programs).